# How to make an operation calls once

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Let's say i have unlimited viewpager and each have been colored.
So on close of the app the operation again being called but what i want is for next start up that operation should not be called again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, this discussion and the [project](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/) link, just try this out:

In `MainActivity` add these two globals:

```
/**
 * {@link SharedPreferences} key for the random int array.
 */
public static final String KEY_RANDOM_INT_FOR_INDEX = "random_int_index";

/**
 * Value holding the total number of images.
 */
public static final int TOTAL_IMAGES = 8;
```

Then at the end of `onCreate` of `MainActivity` again add:

```
// Get a reference to the default SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences defSharedPreference = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
// Check if there is a random int for at least 1 index
if (defSharedPreference.getInt(KEY_RANDOM_INT_FOR_INDEX + "_0", -1) == -1) {
    // Generate array of <TOTAL_IMAGES> random ints;
    ArrayList<Integer> allInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_IMAGES; i++) {
        allInts.add(i);
    }
    // Editor instance for modifying SharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor sp_editor = defSharedPreference.edit();
    // Generate random ints;
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_IMAGES; i++) {
        int range = allInts.size();
        int pickIndex = (int) (Math.random() * range);
        int value = allInts.remove(pickIndex);
        // System.out.print("\nindex: " + i + "\t=\t" + value);
        // Save the random value with the key;
        sp_editor.putInt(KEY_RANDOM_INT_FOR_INDEX + "_" + i, value);
    }
    // Save the editors queue in the SharedPreferences;
    sp_editor.commit();
}
```

Finally in `onCreateView` of `MyFragment` add:

```
// Get a reference to the default SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences defSharedPreference = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
// Calculate the index of the page from base of TOTAL_IMAGES;
int pageIndexInTotalImages = (mCurrentPage - 1)
        % MainActivity.TOTAL_IMAGES;
// Calculate the index of the random image for the page;
int imageID = defSharedPreference.getInt(
        MainActivity.KEY_RANDOM_INT_FOR_INDEX + "_"
                + pageIndexInTotalImages, 0);
int resourceImageID = imageID + R.drawable.image0;
```

Assuming you have the `ImageView` set up in `myfragment_layout`, you can load the image using:

`<ImageView>.setImageResource(resourceImageID);`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74348/discussion-on-answer-by-electrocrat-how-to-make-an-operation-calls-once).

Answer (score 0):

You should use SharedPreferences to store a boolean "firstTime" after that operation. Recover that value before the loop and change the image array.

Comment: Sorry, smartphone App, in a few hours :(

Comment: sir the solution please

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set shared preferences:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("page" + mCurrentPage, randInt);
    editor.commit();
```

To retrieve them, You will need to do something like this:

```
    int randInt = preferences.getInt("page" + mCurrentPage, -1);
```

Code:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int randInt = preferences.getInt("page" + mCurrentPage, -1);
    if(randInt == -1) {
        randInt = new Random().nextInt((8));
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("page" + mCurrentPage, randInt);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: i know how to set shared preference but what approach or how do i do it for the following problem because what i think is if i use share preference here it will only set image for one page where i have 10000 pages in my view pager

Comment: you can store the random int generated with the page number in the sharedprefrences

Comment: i need to implement it in fragment so what do i replace the context with?

Comment: You can use: getActivity()

Comment: it's setting only one image for all the layouts..thats what i was telling that shared preference is not useful in this case

Comment: In order for this to work you need to store a different randInt for each page. Check updated answer

Comment: not working...the code is not working, write the code properly

Comment: What is not working, I'm not sure how I can help you without seeing the rest of the code... I updated my answer with the code.

Comment: your code doesn't work at all it's just showing one single image for all the fields